# Multilayer `Dockerfile` does not `COPY --from=...`: am I doing it wrong?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The entire `Dockerfile` I have:

```
FROM node:16.13.0 as UI
WORKDIR /ui/
COPY ./priv/ui/package.json ./priv/ui/package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
COPY ./priv/ui/ ./
RUN npm run build # <=== this one is OK, it generates static files as expected and where expected

FROM erlang:latest AS PROD

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

RUN ... # some apt stuff to get

COPY --from=UI /ui ./priv/ui/ # <==== PROBLEM IS HERE
...
```

No matter what absolute or related destination I specify (`./priv/ui/` in the example above), it always replies with the same error:

> COPY failed: stat <specified_path>: file does not exist

Comment: Can you try with a lower case stage name (`ui` instead of `UI`)? Image names are case sensitive and must be lower case, and stage names are in the same namespace as image names (if the stage isn't found it falls back to an image).

Comment: @BMitch tried already. Both names and I indexes.

Comment: Condense it down to a [mcve] that doesn't depend on files on your machine and I'll be happy to try reproducing.

Comment: @BMitch I have something even better: https://github.com/zazaeil/zazanet/blob/bug_report/docker/Dockerfile. Will keep `bug_report` branch if you agree to take a look into it. Either `docker-compose build` it from the root or just `docker build -f docker/Dockerfile .`.

Answer (score 0):

I think PROD image haven't /priv/ui folder; so you can create using "mkdir -p" command like below

```
 ...
    FROM erlang:latest AS PROD
    
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
    
    RUN mkdir -p /priv/ui # <b> could you try </b>
    
    COPY --from=UI /ui ./priv/ui/ # <==== PROBLEM IS HERE
    ...
```

Comment: Tried that as well. Nope, it doesn't work either.